# Wagtail Factories Issue

Tags: wagtail

Wagtail Factories issue after moving from Wagtail 2.15.6 to Wagtail 4.1.5

Error is

self = <core.blocks.RouteSectionBlock object at 0x10f170700>, value = <class 'tests.unit.domestic.factories.RouteSectionFactory'>

def get_prep_value(self, value):

"""Recursively call get_prep_value on children and return as a plain dict"""

return {

name: self.child_blocks[name].get_prep_value(val)

> for name, val in value.items()

}

E       AttributeError: type object 'RouteSectionFactory' has no attribute 'items'

venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/blocks/struct_block.py:214: AttributeError

Our Factories are

```
class DomesticDashboardFactory(wagtail_factories.PageFactory):
    title = 'Title of Dashboard'
    live = True
    slug = 'dashboard'

    components = wagtail_factories.StreamFieldFactory({'route': RouteSectionFactory})

    class Meta:
        model = DomesticDashboard


class RouteSectionFactory(wagtail_factories.StructBlockFactory):
    title = 'Title'
    route_type = 'learn'
    body = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyText(length=60)
    image = None
    button = None

    class Meta:
        model = core_blocks.RouteSectionBlock
```

our model is

```
class RouteSectionBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    # One of the three intro blocks at the top of the domestic dashboard
    route_type = blocks.ChoiceBlock(
        choices=[
            ('learn', 'Learning'),
            ('plan', 'Export plan'),
            ('target', 'Target market'),
        ],
        icon='redirect',
    )
    title = blocks.CharBlock(max_length=255)
    body = blocks.TextBlock(max_length=4096)
    image = ImageChooserBlock()
    button = ButtonBlock(icon='cog', required=False)

    class Meta:
        help_text = 'The routing block at the top of the dashboard. There should be three - learn, target, plan'
        template = 'core/includes/_route-section.html'
        icon = 'redirect'
```

Our test is failing at

```
ashboard = DomesticDashboardFactory(
        parent=domestic_homepage,
        slug='dashboard',
        components__0__route__route_type='learn',
        components__0__route__title='Learning title',
        components__0__route__body='Learning Body Text',
        components__0__route__button={'label': 'Start learning'},
        components__1__route__route_type='target',
        components__1__route__title='Target title',
        components__1__route__body='Target Body Text',
        components__1__route__button={'label': 'Start targetting'},
        components__2__route__route_type='plan',
        components__2__route__title='Planning title',
        components__2__route__body='Planning Body Text',
        components__2__route__button={'label': 'Start planning'},
    )
```

with error above, seems like we have to add an items atribute but what should this be set to ?